# Android Studio [Tab Layout]: ¿Como mover una tab layout a la parte inferior de la actividad?

Tags: android

Estoy teniendo varios problemas con la **actividad tabbeada**:

**1 -** ¿Que código permite mostrar en las tabs **íconos** con el **tamaño que yo le indique**?

**2 -** ¿Como puedo modificar mi **archivo xml** para hacer que la TabLayout se muestre en el **lado inferior**, en lugar de el lado superior?

**Adjunto información para la pregunta 1:**
Este es el código que logré encontrar para modificar las tabs con imágenes:

```
 tabss.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_perfil_negro); //PERFIL
 tabss.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_gastos_negro); //TRANSACCIONES
 tabss.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_configuracion_negro); //CONFIG.
```

**Así se ven los archivos XML de los íconos:** (Aviso que ya intenté cambiar los valores de ancho y alto del ícono para comprobar si este cambio de tamaño se vería reflejado en los íconos que se muestran en las tabs (No funcionó))

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="30dp"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
 <path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,12c2.21,0 4,-1.79 4,-4s-1.79,-4 -4,-4 -4,1.79 -4,4 
 1.79,4 4,4zM12,14c-2.67,0 -8,1.34 -8,4v2h16v-2c0,-2.66 -5.33,-4 -8,-4z"/>
 </vector>
```

**Adjunto información para la pregunta 2:** Este es el código xml de la actividad Tabbeada:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context="com.example.ui.CHAT.fragment_contenedor_chat">

 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tabss"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         app:tabTextColor="#000000"
         app:tabIndicatorColor="#b2dfdb"/>
 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/view_pagerr"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Imágen de como se ve mi actividad tabbeada:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradezco mucho la lectura de mi pregunta, y espero poder obtener respuesta para las 3 dudas**.

Comment: debes de hacer uso del método onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Hola Fernando y gracias por responder. Podrías detallar mejor tu respuesta? Es que hice 3 preguntas puntuales.

Comment: no te estoy dando como tal una respuesta a tu problema, simplemente te comento que debes hacer uso del  onCreateOptionsMenu  para el tema que necesitas, puedes revisar en alguna doc oficial para ver cómo funciona, no consideres esto como una respuesta válida sino como un comentario. Disculpa

Comment: Ok fernando buenisimo. Obviamente lo tomo. Agradezco por la ayuda!

Comment: de nada, amigo y una disculpa, espero que te sirva de algo

Comment: ya has intentado mover **ViewPager** arriba de **TabLayout**?

Comment: Si, pero no cambió nada.